# Need help about DNS Zone

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange

I need to redirect my MX record to our new Exchange Server but there is things that I don't get ...

My domain name his provided by OVH and my hosting is at 2MHOST. So in my OVH control panel the DNS (NS1 and NS2) are pointing to 2MHOST servers.

But both of them give me possibility to edit MX record, I can do it by OVH (Manager -> DNS Zone) or by 2MHOST (via cPanel).

Who has the priority ??

The company who have installed us the Exchange server told me that I needed to create a subdomain that point to our server IP and then change the MX record to that subdomain and also ask my ISP to create a reverse DNS to that subdomain.

I am a bit lost of what and where I am supposed to do the stuff.

- I have activated DNS zone from OVH right now, because there were not active and it look like it's the only way to create a subdomain redirecting to our IP (ZONE A).
- I can't nslookup that subdomain, maybe it take a little time ?
- Now I need to change the MX record from my Host or from OVH (DNS zone) ?

Thank if someone can help me out a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the 2MHOST cPanel will be where you need to setup the subdomain A and domain MX record if they are the zones DNS servers (your NS1 + NS2). The reverse delegation for your IP address will need to be done by the supplier who owns the IP block for your mail servers IP, which is likely the supplier/isp/network hosting the mail server

While you are configuring this you should also setup a TXT record for [SPF](http://support.google.com/postini/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=132370) so mail servers can tell where your domains mail should be coming from.

To confirm what the real world sees as your dns servers, you can use the [dig](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) tool or there are various [online tools](http://www.kloth.net/services/dig.php) that let you complete the same queries.

To get your name servers, do an `NS` lookup

```
dig NS yourdomain.com
```

Are these 2MHOST servers?

To confirm, setup your new subdomain for the mail server in the 2MHost Cpanel you can check the new name has appeared on those DNS servers.

```
dig @ns1answer.com subdomain.yourdomain.com
dig @ns2answer.com subdomain.yourdomain.com
```

You can do the same confirmation once you make the MX change

```
dig @ns1 MX yourdomain.com
dig @ns2 MX yourdomain.com
```

Then wait for the updates to propagate through the dns caches.

Comment: Now the nslookup of the subdomain created from 2MHOST is correctly pointing to our IP, maybe it needed a few hours or a DNS refresh I don't know.. So you mean that the DNS Zone change I have made iin my OVH panel has strictly no effect as my main NS are pointing to 2MHOST ? I don't need to try to reverse change I have made there ?

Comment: I couldn't say for sure, contact OVH support for that but on the surface it sounds that way. It's always possible the DNS servers could be slaved to each other.  I have the same type of setup. Domains are with a registrar who provides all the DNS hosting options as well so the web management interface provides the options but use external NS's so I configure elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Open http://who.is/whois/yourdomain.com to find out to which name server your domain points. This name server has the "priority".

It's also the server where you have to create the subdomain. You can tell `nslookup` which server it should query, so this should work as soon as you created the record.

Btw. The reverse entry has to be made by the provider of that IP. If you are not the provider, you propably can't do that yourself.

Comment: Bad idea to use whois to check the DNS setup. The only authoritative info is in the DNS (in theory, whois should show the same thing. In theory)

Comment: I disagree. It's a very easy and effective way to find out the name server delegation of a domain.

Comment: But it's not reliable, specially in thin registries like ".com".